# Open file and create 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, text-files

I have the file `mapData.txt`, which contains several arrays:

```
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

How would I open this file, and create a 2D array using these lines?
For example, after creating the 2D array (called, say, "`worldMap`"), if I were to type:

```
print(worldMap[0][0])
```

It would print `1`

Comment: Who decided on this serialization format? And do you mean *list* rather than array?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I can change the format of the file if needed. I thought "list" and "array" were synonymous?

Comment: They are not synonymous. An array is a very primitive data structure. You rarely manipulate arrays directly in python, unless you use `numpy`, where the arrays there are basically object-oriented wrappers around C arrays. A list is actually an abstract data type, but in Python, lists are resizable array-lists with optimized operations like `append` and `extend` with amortized constant time performance. They are also heterogenous containers, wheras arrays are generally homogenous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add error handling code but this seems to work at least with your example:

```
import json

worldMap = []
with open('mapData.txt', 'r') as datafile:
    for line in datafile:
        worldMap.append(json.loads(line))
    print(worldMap[0][0])
```

Comment: @MaxHeslop if you are just going to use `json` on each line, you might as well just use `json` from the beginning!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm afraid that your answer did not work

Comment: @MaxHeslop I am literally copy-and-pasting your string as you've posted it, and you can see the results of running it in my terminal. In any event, using `json` from the beginning **definitely works**. It makes no sense to deserialize each individual line using `json`... just serialize the *whole data structure*

Answer (score 1):

As a straightforward, and so efficient approach, you can just use `numpy.genfromtxt`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.genfromtxt('a.txt', delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Yeah, but that requires `numpy`, which is not exactly a library you use simply to have a handy way to load arrays. Also, this will not work with the parentheses.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It doesn't matter it requires what. Numpy is a library like another python built-in libraries you just need to install it like Cpython interpreter itself. The only thing that matters is what is correct and then better which in this case, in addition to loading the text in most optimized way it will return a numpy array which also has a lot of advantages for future operations. (It can also encourage the OP to learn something new and so appropriate for his/her needs)

Comment: `numpy` is *not* like the built-in libraries. It is a third-party library that isn't always trivial to install -- especially on non-unix platforms. We cannot know for sure whether or not a `numpy` array or a vanilla python `list` is preferable in this case. However, we can surmise that the OP is writing some sort of world-map for a small, game-like project. That definitely does *not* sound like a use-case for `numpy`, especially if your list of lists is 16x16... for such small structures `numpy` is likely *slower* than regular python.

Comment: @Kasramvd there is also compiled exe package for windows. with GIS distribution you can add it with ArcGIS solution or OsGeo4W installer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to evaluate each line in your file, or parse it yourself as follows:

```
>>> def parse_line(line):
...     return line.strip('\n[]').split(',')
...
>>> with open('myfile.txt') as f:
...     world_map = [list(map(int,parse_line(line))) for line in f]
...
>>> pprint(world_map)
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
>>>
```

But you should really consider using an existing text-serialization format, like `json`. So, for example:

```
>>> my_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> import json
>>> with open('my_list.json', 'w') as f:
...     json.dump(my_list, json)
...
```

So the above writes the `json` file to disk. Now, to load from disk:

```
>>> with open('my_list.json') as f:
...     list2 = json.load(f)
...
>>> list2
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>>
```

Comment: @Kasramvd what?

Comment: I get the error "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1]'"

Comment: Sorry I got confused by term `ast.literal_eval`. But still this is not efficient at all, just use `ast.literal_eval` for each line, at least.

Comment: @Kasramvd you can go either way, I suppose. `ast.literal_eval` is slow, in general. It is also just hacky, in my opinion, although, parsing like this is also hacky. I updated with some elaboration on using `json` to begin with.

Comment: @MaxHeslop are you sure you stripping the whitespace?

Comment: @Kasramvd I have same think but json is more efficient

Comment: You have to use a parser either way - either rolling your own like above or retrofitting `json` or using the Python parser itself (e.g. `ast.literal_eval` or `eval`).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga and why not pandas or numpy array?

Comment: @GeoStoneMarten because that is almost certainly overkill in this scenario - and the original question did not indicate either of those libraries... The "correct" answer, IMO, is simply to use `json` from the beginning.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok that is just my culture is GIS and data manipulation... Thanks.